# C++ armadillo - assign values to column

Tags: c++, armadillo

How can I assign values to a column of an armadillo matrix?

Let's say I have a 2x2 matrix (initialized to zeros) and I want to fill the second column with arbitrary values e.g [1; 3]

In MATLAB I would do something like:

```
A(:,2)=[1; 3]
```

However when I try:

```
A.col(1) << 1 << endr << 3 << endr;
```

I get en error as operator `<<` is not supported by subviews.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

```
A.col(1) = vec({1,2});
```

If you're working with C++11 ?