# Is there a way to select a single column in a matrix within armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

Is there a way to select all the elements within a column in a matrix in C++ armadillo library?

For example, in MATLAB, I can use : to refer to all the elements within a column of the matrix:

```
A = ones(5,5);    
A(:,1) = A(:,1) * 5;
```

Here, I have choose to multiply by 5 all elements within column 1.

```
A =

     5     1     1     1     1
     5     1     1     1     1
     5     1     1     1     1
     5     1     1     1     1
     5     1     1     1     1
```

I have searched the documentation of armadillo but I didn't find what I need. Can I do that with armadillo?

Comment: I found a similar question on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452281/c-armadillo-assign-values-to-column?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multiply the fist column of matrix `A` by 5, use `A.col(0) *= 5`.

The documentation has a [syntax conversion table](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax) between Armadillo and Matlab.

The documentation also describes the many forms of [submatrices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat).